# Validating phone number in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm trying to validate a textfield phone number, such that the input will match the following pattern: 05x-xxxxxxx (hyphen is ignored).
Is this the correct way of doing it?

**HTML:**

```
<form name="PhoneForm">
    <div>
        <md-icon md-svg-src="icons/ic_phone_48px.svg"></md-icon>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input ng-model="contactPhone" name="PhoneInput" required ng-pattern="[0][5][0-9]{8}"/> <!-- i.e 05x-xxxxxxx -->
            <div ng-messages="PhoneForm.PhoneInput.$error" ng-if="PhoneForm.PhoneInput.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required!</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Illegal phone number!</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

Because this doesn't seem to work. I'm not even getting the "field is required" message when the input is empty. Could something be wrong with the pattern?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the REGEX. I would suggest putting in the REGEX start/end expressions (^ and $) and wrapping the expression with `/`. In the following plunker `/^[0][5][0-9]{8}$/` works as you intend with `ng-pattern`.

Plunk is based on the one in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

https://embed.plnkr.co/BsJXjqIE1TwzT7OPFvNA/

Answer (score 0):

remove the `required` attribute from the input tag if its not required.